# Every circuit of size at most $S$ can be representd as a string of $9S \log S$ bits

Tags: complexity-theory, circuits

I'm trying to understand this claim. I see that if there are $S$ vertices, then we can identify each vertex using $\log S$ bits. Now each vertex can be connected to, let's say, $S$ other ones (is there some sort of restriction to the fan-out that I'm unaware of?). If we use an adjacency list, then for each vertex, we wold need to store up to $S \log S$ bits. Doesn't this lead to $S^2 \log S$ bits, since we need a list for each vertex? And where does the $9$ come from?

Comment: Some models of circuits have restrictions on the fan-in of gates.

Comment: Where have you seen this claim?

Comment: This is in Arora and Barak's "Computational Complexity". There is indeed a restriction on the fan-in (2 or less), but not on the fan-out, as far as I can tell.

Comment: A restriction on the fan-in is all you need.

Comment: Because then for each vertex we list the incoming vertices, rather than the outgoing ones? Then I think we can represent the circuit with $2S \log S$ bits, but why the $9$ in the claim?

Comment: Right, that’s the idea. The constant 9 is probably an arbitrary constant that works, but could be reduced. We usually don’t care much about such constants.

Comment: Yes, I have been coming to terms with this, but sometimes these constants seem absurdly arbitrary...